# jQuery substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a key value pair something like this. this response comes back from the service in API.

```
var str = { "key1":"value1",..}
```

I need to use something lik this

```
for(var value in str) {

//I need to get only the value here. Eg: value1,value2 etc
}
```

how to get only value1 from this array using jquery sub string?

Comment: You don't. I think you need to use `array['key1']`. Im not sure why you would need a loop if you are only trying to fetch one single value.

Comment: What do you need `substring` for? What is `str`?

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through an object (= key/value store) like this:

```
for (var key in items) {
    var value = items[key];
    // do things with key and value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response comes back as a set of (key, value) pairs, then you cannot really select the "first" value, because JSON objects do *not* have an order to their fields (different parsers may and probably will return the values in different order).  You must know which key you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = { "key1":"value1",..}



for(var val in str) {

  var strval = str[val];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = { "key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key2":"value2"};

var keyItems,valItems;
for(key in str){
   keyItems.push(key);
   valItems.push(str[key]);
}

// keyItems is array of all keys
// valItems is array of all values.
```